# MVVM repository in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm, android-mvvm

Am working on a huge android project that has more than 50 APIs request
and using the MVVM pattern, My question is:
can I add all the requests in the same app repository or I must create a repository for each service?

[image]

Comment: You should create *Repositories* based on **your modules** (like login, product, cart etc.).

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested in the comments you should first define the modules of your app and then create the corresponding Repositories. This way you can easily maintain and test your application.

I strongly suggest you to have a look on this https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid and mostly this video https://youtu.be/Sy6ZdgqrQp0

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to this problem is, You must not implement all your API calling code to the same repository as it will become a massive single repository class. It will also be violating design principles i.e.  [rule of 30](https://dzone.com/articles/rule-30-%E2%80%93-when-method-class-or) as you are saying you have at least 50 APIs to work with. 
Also, it is not a good practice to modify a class, again and again, see [Open Close Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). 
 You can make multiple API calling classes under the same package name.